# Am I using headers properly in python Twisted using getPage?

Tags: python, html, header, twisted

Below us my callback for fetching a page using twisted.

```
     client.getPage(iUrl,headers,method='GET',cookies=cj).addCallback(self.processPage,iUrl).addErrback(self.printError,iUrl)
```

Here is the format for my headers.

```
headers = Headers({'content-type': ['text/html; charset=utf-8'], 'user-agent': ["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11'"]})
```

I know the user agent works if I use urllib2 because I can extract fields that require a header.  Using this header in twisted does not work and I suspect how I am using headers in twisted. So, what is to proper way to specify a header in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `headers` parameter to `twisted.web.client.getPage` accepts a `dict`, not a `twisted.web.http_headers.Headers` instance.

Answer (score 3):

HTTPClientFactory (used internally by getPage) constructor signature looks like:

```
3       def __init__(self, url, method='GET', postdata=None, headers=None,
204                  agent="Twisted PageGetter", timeout=0, cookies=None,
205                  followRedirect=1):
```

thus try passing headers as keyword param:

```
client.getPage(iUrl,method='GET',cookies=cj, headers=headers)...
```

headers themselves look quite normal for me.

Comment: As Jean-Paul mentions above, the headers argument should be a `dict`, not a `Headers` instance.